# Is this demonstration of convergence not a bit too complicated?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let be $$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
~0 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
~1 & \text{if } x=\frac{1}{n}\\
~0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}%$$

$g$ is affine and continuous if $x\leq 0$:  $g_n(x)$ is constant and equals to $0$.

*if $x\geq 0$ then let be $N$ such that $\frac{2}{N}\leq x$ then the sequence  $g_n(x)$ is constant and equal to $0$ from some rank $N$ thus the sequence is constant and equal to $0$ from a given rank $N$.*

Thus $g_n(x)\rightarrow 0, \forall x\in \ \mathbb{R}$

I'm not quite sure to understand the passage in italic. Indeed it goes without saying that from a given rank $N$, as far as the third case of the equation system is $0$ when it goes beyond $\frac{1}{N}$

Comment: It does go without saying, but if one decides to say, some length is inevitable. And things are made more complicated by what looks like machine translation.

Comment: I'm not a machine! I'm a man! I've got the love of humanity in my heart!